# Reset jquery draggable elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, reset, jquery-ui-droppable

I want to reset all elements in list to initial position. this is my example [Jquery UI Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager)

this is my reset function

```
$(".reset").click(function() {
       // Code to reset all elements
});
```

How can i do it?

Comment: You have got to be kidding me! `// Code to reset all elements` is a comment, not js code, and all you did is a basic bind of a click event to element with `reset` class

Comment: And for "your" example (which is actually the demo from jqueryUI), you can [destroy](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#method-destroy) the droppable functionality and return the element to the original state, and the you can define the droppable again on the original element)

Comment: Upvote and accept my answer if it helps you, so other people know this is the correct answer and helps them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code below:

**First set order attribute to items**

```
// This code used for set order attribute for items
var numberOfItems = $("#gallery").find('li').length;
$.each($("#gallery").find('li'), function(index, item) {
    $(item).attr("order", index);
});
```

**Change recycleImage function**

```
function recycleImage($item) {
    $item.fadeOut(function() {
        $item
            .find("a.ui-icon-refresh")
            .remove()
            .end()
            .css("width", "96px")
            .append(trash_icon)
            .find("img")
            .css("height", "72px")
            .end()
            //.appendTo($gallery)                 
            .fadeIn();
            // Add to old palce
            addToOlderPlace($item);
    });
}
```

**Add addToOlderPlace function**

```
// This function used for find old place of item
function addToOlderPlace($item) {
    var indexItem = $item.attr('order');
    var itemList = $("#gallery").find('li');
    if (indexItem === numberOfItems - 1)
        $("#gallery").append($item);
    else if (indexItem === "0")
        $("#gallery").prepend($item);
    else
        $(itemList[indexItem - 1]).after($item);
}
```

[**Online demo (fiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/051vbt2z/1/)

Comment: @fray Please up-vote my answer for knowing and helping other people that it helps you because some people only see the up-voted answers.